# Android, sharedpreferences or internal storage?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, data-storage

I want to store some basic data like players_name,levels_completed,fastest_speed,fastest_time and bring it up each time the player starts a silly little game I am making... which is the perffered method to do this?

Sharedprefs or internal storage?

I am at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html
and have just gotten confused as to which to use as both look good and easy enough to do.

Advise?

Thanks!

Comment: to me the key/value storage that sharedprefs provides is much easier/less of a hassle to work with - just my take though. Hopefully somebody else can chime in with more info for you though :)

Comment: Thanks Alex, if it isnt a secret would you mind sharing some code on how you implement it? Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is pretty much taken from one of the Facebook sdks examples (it allows you to save the FB session so the user doesn't have to login each time)... I'll modify it a bit for you though

```
public class SessionStore {

private static final String PLAYER_NAME = "player_name";
private static final String LEVELS_COMPLETED = "levels_completed";
private static final String HIGH_SCORE = "high_score";

private static final String KEY = "player_session";

int highScore;
int levelsCompleted;
String pName;

public static boolean saveSession(Context context, String player_name, int levels_completed, int high_score) {
    Editor editor =
        context.getSharedPreferences(KEY + player_name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString(PLAYER_NAME,player_name);
    editor.putInt(LEVELS_COMPLETED, levels_completed);
    editor.putInt(HIGH_SCORE,high_score);

    return editor.commit();
}

public static void restoreSession(Context context, String player_name) {
    SharedPreferences savedSession =
        context.getSharedPreferences(KEY + player_name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    highScore = savedSession.getInt(HIGH_SCORE,0);
    levelsCompleted = savedSession.getInt(LEVELS_COMPLETED,0);
    pName = savedSession.getString(PLAYER_NAME,"NO_NAME!");

}

public String getName()
{
      return pName;
}
```

}

I think you get the basic idea...

some points: I use "KEY + player_name" in case different players play on the same phone (if it was static you would overwrite the data of one player with anothers data).

Also, when you do `pName = savedSession.getString(PLAYER_NAME,"NO_NAME!");` if nothing exists in the shared preferences it defaults to the value "NO_NAME!" and likewise for the getInts (which in this case I have them default to 0)

in the program you would do `SessionStore.saveSession("Alex",50000,50000);` to save the session, etc.  Hope this gives a good gist of how to use it... Also keep in mind I'm an android newb - this works great for me but I'm no expert :D

Comment: Thanks dude! I'll wait for a while, if no one else writes in with advise that is against what you wrote I'll pick your answer

Answer (score 1):

If it is game data that is static you could use shared preferences. If it is dynamic data like player high scores etc I would use sqlite database. I actually think that a database is a simpler option as creating read / write buffers can be a bit tricky on internal storage.

```
public void StoreTimeAppend(String MY_DATA, File file) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(String.valueOf(file), MODE_APPEND);
        Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF8");
        out.write(MY_DATA + '\n');
        out.close();
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Tip.setText("ISSUE");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have not come to databases as yet :( still in the early stages of my book so thats not an option for me right now. Itsonly between preferences and internal storage. Thanks!

Comment: Oh I see. I cant guarantee this is correct (I only use databases now) but for my first app I used internal storage. I used a file input stream and a stream writer to store information and it worked just fine.

Comment: I have my app on my other computer. Ill start it up and post some code for you.

Comment: So many new people starting Android, and I was scared I would be one of the only newbs on this site :)) Thakns Adam, will wait and check out the code

Comment: okay, so I wrote a function to write to a file I passed as a parameter

Comment: public void StoreTimeAppend( String MY_ITEM, File file) {

    try {

    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(String.valueOf(file), MODE_APPEND);

    Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF8");

    out.write( MY_ITEM + '\n');

    out.close();

    fos.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {}

    }

Comment: Can you edit your answer to add that please, and I think (if I understand it correctly) thats to insert, whats the code to read?